# Swift table view with few rows can be scrolled up

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll, rows

I have this table view which in some cases contains few rows, even one.
What’s wrong with it is that even if I have one row, it allows me to scroll down and the row gets hidden at top.

It practically almost disappears from screen, as if there would be somethingto show below it.
I can’t disable scrolling because I have pull down to refresh.

Any ideas if there is a setting I am missing? Or how I could not allow scroll down if I do not have enough rows to cover the whole screen?

Comment: Actually it is called as `tableView assertion failure`. If you check the logs, you will see this. The problem is that you are trying to update the `tableView`'s `datasource` in improper manner.

Comment: @New16 I have looked up "tableView assertion failure". It looks like an error that terminates the app session and I am not getting it. Since I was not able to find an example of "tableView assertion failure" that does not result in an error can you help me with more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your case is kind of tricky, because:

The first I thought that the solution will be `myTableView.alwaysBounceVertical = false`

That's will do the job for you, but the problem in your case that you have a `UIRefreshControl()` and setting `alwaysBounceVertical` to `false` will disable scrolling to top for displaying the refreshController.

So, it should be done manually, as follows:

**1-** Implement the *scrollViewDidScroll* method from `UIScrollViewDelegate`.

**2-** check the scrolling direction in it.

**3-** if the scrolling direction goes down, check if content size of the tableView is more than its height, i.e check if tableView contains cell more than its height.

**4-** if the output of step 3 is false, disable scrolling, else, enable scrolling.

**5-** add `dispatch_after` to re-enable tableView scrolling.

It goes like this (*Note: Swift 2 code.*):

```
private var lastContentOffset: CGFloat = 0
    // 1
    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        // 2
        if (self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
            print("scrolling up")
        }
        else if (self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
            print("scrolling down")

            // 3 and 4
            myTableView.scrollEnabled = myTableView.contentSize.height > myTableView.frame.size.height ? true : false

            // 5

            // delaying is half a second
            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(NSEC_PER_MSEC) * 500), dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.myTableView.scrollEnabled = true
            })
        }
    }
```

Hope this is a good solution for your case.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to take into consideration exactly the situation and explain so detailed. Your solution worked perfectly for me. I will put here your code with some small updates I made because of some errors popping up.

Comment: if (self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
        }
        else if (self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
            tableView.isScrollEnabled = tableView.contentSize.height > tableView.frame.size.height ? true : false
  
            let dispatchTime: DispatchTime = DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(0.1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: dispatchTime, execute: {
                self.tableView.isScrollEnabled = true
            })
        }

Comment: I have already accepted your answer, but if you can, please update it with the small changes I made so that it is helpful for others.

Comment: I'm glad to help :). You are using swift 3, so I suggest to add an answer coded via Swift 3 and note viewers that's it is the same answer for Swift 3 users.